# How to identify the root cause of excess memory consumption in a Heroku Python deployment?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, plotly-dash

I have recently deployed a web app on Heroku (Free version). The deployment uses Python with libraries for plotly, dash, pandas and bootstrap. I would assume that this setup based on the size of all the files should only be in few 10s of MBs. However, it is consuming over 400 MB of RAM. How do I troubleshoot to identify the cause of this high memory (possibly a memory leak)?

I have tried using the heroku labs logs-runtime-metrics tool but the information is limited. I also tried to use the chrome developer tools but I was not able to reach anywhere.

```
heroku labs:enable log-runtime-metrics
heroku logs
```

The log looks something like this:

```
heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.XXXX sample#memory_total=458.20MB sample#memory_rss=431.30MB sample#memory_cache=26.89MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=160223pages sample#memory_pgpgout=49568pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
```

As I mentioned above the memory_rss value which translated to the actual RAM consumption is too high for a python based function (close to the limit). Running the same process on my local machine peaks at around 180MB. Does the import of Python modules affect memory performance too much?

Looking for advice or help to point me in the right direction, please. Appreciate your help. Thanks.

---

**EDIT 1: gunicorn --preload and improved codebase**

I have tried to improve the memory optimization somewhat by using this hack where one can preload the application as explained here:
[Gunicorn Preload](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#app-preloading)

This is done by editing the Procfile to contain the following:

```
web: gunicorn hello:app --preload
```

I also did some edits in the way I was importing certain libraries and avoiding others whose purpose could be overridden. With all that my new logs show a decent improvement:

```
heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.XXXX sample#memory_total=272.63MB sample#memory_rss=248.45MB sample#memory_cache=24.18MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=97938pages sample#memory_pgpgout=28145pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
```

More inputs are welcome!

Comment: I don't have any tips or tools for you, but bear in mind that the memory consumption Heroku reports likely includes things like your web server (and maybe some system-level processes since everything is running in a container) that you probably aren't considering locally.

Comment: That makes sense. I have done some minor optimizations (EDIT 1 in question) that have helped me. But this method also seems to slow the page loading I feel (have to measure it)